# HOSTFXR.DLL FAILED TO LOAD

Tags: .net, .net-core

### I'm trying to install this app from Github; https://github.com/EDavis66/AMM-sniper-bot, and when I do so, I get an error message:

### Error

### A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.\nIf this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\qweas\netcoreapp3.1].\nIf this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [C:\Program Files\dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].

Note that I've installed NETCORE SDK, specifically;
C:\Users\Administrator>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version: 6.0.201
Commit: ef40e6aa06

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Windows
OS Version: 10.0.17763
OS Platform: Windows
RID: win10-x64
Base Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\

Host (useful for support):
Version: 6.0.3
Commit: c24d9a9c91

.NET SDKs installed:
6.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

I have set the dotnet_root env variable to C:\Program Files\dotnet.
I did this via ;
Control Panel\System & Security\System\Advanced System Settings\Environmental Variables, selected system variables, and then path.
What am I doing wrong?[pic of environmental variables settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clvqM.png)

Comment: You've got the download link, click on ".NET Core 3.1"

Comment: @HansPassant I believe that I have already downloaded .NET SDK and installed it. When I run the command 'dotnet --info' on my command prompt, the following info is spit out ;
.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: @HansPassant The stated libraryhost.fxr error still persists. What .NET file do I appear to be missing?

Comment: The error message clearly states "netcoreapp3.1".  That's not 6.0